# VBA word Invalid Qualifier error using Dynamic Ranges to replace blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing a small section of code that will run through doing the following:

1. Find the maximum size of the data block (what is the last cell with
   data in and the coordinates, given by LRow and LCol)
2. search through the data within a column (would like to make this a range of columns) and if a cell is blank then use the value of the cell above it.
3. Create a new sheet and rename
4. Go through the data select only those rows that have the word "Fatal" within column k, and paste those rows into the new renamed sheet.

Below is my code so far. Can anyone implement the improvements I mentioned above, and also figure out why I obtain an Invalid Qualifier error with LRow?
The code is initiated from a Word document to open an excel spreadsheet and play with data in the spreadsheet.

Click on button to activate the global sub:

```
Private Sub ObtainFatalCrashInfoButton_Click()
'Disable screen updating
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run ("OpenRawDataFile")
Application.Run ("FixData")
Application.Run ("GetData")
'Application.Run ("CloseRawDataFile")
Application.Run ("CommandButtonRemove")
'Enable screen updating
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Then the following subs are activated in turn:

```
Sub OpenRawDataFile()
'Not sure this works....
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim IFAM_Index As Variant

Dim IFAM_File As Variant

IFAM_File = appExcel.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls), *.xls")

appExcel.Workbooks.Open IFAM_File

End Sub
```

Sub FixData. Adds in missing data to make the next part of the process easier

```
Sub FixData()
Dim i As Long
Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
Dim rngD As Range

'Set the range of the "Duration Working" Spreadsheet
LRow = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rngD = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LRow, LCol))


For i = 1 To LRow.Rows.Count
    If LRow.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
        LRow.Cells(i, 11).Value = LRow.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Sub GetData(). SUb should copy the rows meeting the criteria into a new sheet to make it easier to extract to word in the required format (this part is yet to be written).

```
Sub GetData()

'Create new tab to copy data to
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets.Add

'assuming the data is in sheet1
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
RowCount = LRow
For jj = 1 To RowCount
    'assuming the true statment is in column k
    Range("k" & jj).Select
    check_value = ActiveCell
    If check_value = "Fatal" Or check_value = "fatal" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
        'assuming the data is in sheet2
        WS.Select
        RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "k").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("k" & RowCount + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Sub CopyData(). TO be written. Will copy data across to word in a specific format. Any suggestions anyone?

```
Sub CopyData()
'....To be written
End Sub
```

Sub CloseRawDataFile. Closes the raw data file without saving as the data should now be copied to word in the required format.

```
Sub CloseRawDataFile()

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Sub CommandButtonRemove. Remove the command button from the word document as the process will not be required again.

```
Sub CommandButtonRemove()
Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
If iShp.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
    If iShp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "ObtainFatalCrashInfoButton" Then
        iShp.Range.Font.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Ultimately this code will search through the data set and paste the contents meeting a criteria into the word document in a predefined table. I have tried to isolate small components of the code as I go to make it easier. Hence the only looking at searching the code and pasting into a new table at this stage.

Any help on the other parts yet to be written would also be a great help!

Comment: A variable of type Long doesn't have a `Rows` property.  Maybe you just want `For i = 1 To LRow`

Comment: ^^ Nor does it have a `Cells` property.  Is `LRow.Cells` meant to be `wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells`?

Comment: ^^^ or maybe `For i = 1 To LRow.Rows.Count` should be `For i = 1 To rngD.Rows.Count` and `LRow.Cells` should be `rngD.Cells`

Comment: I just noticed that you say that this code is being used in Word, not in Excel, but all your objects seem to be assuming that you are running in native Excel (e.g. use of `ActiveSheet` and unqualified `Range` objects).  Can you show more of your code so that we can see how you are creating your Excel Application object, etc.  (I would normally have replaced the inappropriate [word] tag with a [ms-word] one, but I didn't see anything in the code that seemed to make it Word VBA, so I just deleted the [word] tag thinking you had used it because of "rows that have the *word* "Fatal" " bit.)

Comment: I have a word document with a click button shown on the page. Upon clicking this the code starts a global program that has application run for each sub. I have updated the main article to include these.

Comment: Where are you defining your `wb` object which you are using in your `FixData` subroutine?  And, unless you have included a reference to the Excel library (which seems unlikely if you are using late-binding), you will also need to define all your constants (such as `xlUp`) somewhere, because they won't be automatically available in Word.  And `Range` is a completely different object in Word than in Excel, so that will need to be done differently.  And you won't have any "default" objects such as `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` when you just say `Rows.Count`.  Etc, etc.

Comment: Hmm I thought I had referenced wb in the OpenRawDataFile sub. However, I did change the method of opening, so that may be why its not there. Is there a better method of opening the spreadsheet than that I've used? I'm used to Excel VBA coding and assumed that code was applicable once the excel workbook was open.

Comment: Before you will be able to successfully write code using two different `Application` objects (in your case, a Word one and an Excel one) you have to get into the habit of **always** fully qualifying references to objects.  And before you can successfully write code in nice discrete chunks like you are trying to do (which is a good thing! :) ) you need to understand variable scope - e.g. the use of `LRow` in `GetData` isn't going to work because you have defined `LRow` to have procedure-level scope within the `FixData` procedure, so `GetData` knows nothing about that variable.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this as a potential fix for your `FixData` routine.  Even if it doesn't actually do what you intended, it might give you some idea of the things you are going to have to handle to get the rest of your code working.

```
'Force developer to declare every variable that is being used
Option Explicit

'Define module-level scoped variables, which will be available to all
'procedures in this code module
Private appExcel As Object
Private wb As Object
Private LRow As Long
'Need to define all the constants that are normally available in Excel VBA
Private Const xlUp As Long = -4162
Private Const xlToLeft As Long = -4159

Private Sub ObtainFatalCrashInfoButton_Click()
    OpenRawDataFile
    'Disable screen updating
    appExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
    FixData
    'Application.Run ("GetData")
    'Application.Run ("CloseRawDataFile")
    'Application.Run ("CommandButtonRemove")
    'Enable screen updating
    appExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub OpenRawDataFile()
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim IFAM_Index As Variant
    Dim IFAM_File As Variant

    IFAM_File = appExcel.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls), *.xls")

    'Create a workbook object that we can refer to
    Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(IFAM_File)
End Sub

Sub FixData()
    Dim i As Long
    'Your question implies that you need LRow to be module-level scope
    ' so remove declaration from here
    'Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim LCol As Long
    '"As Range" in Word means "As Word.Range".  If you are using
    ' late-binding to access Excel, you need to declare rngD "As Object"
    'Dim rngD As Range
    Dim rngD As Object

    'Set the range of the "Duration Working" Spreadsheet
    '"Rows" and "Columns" need to be qualified, because Word doesn't know that
    ' you really mean that to be "appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows", etc,
    ' (and you probably didn't mean that anyway)
    'LRow = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'LCol = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LRow = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    '"Range" and "Cells" need to be qualified, because Word doesn't know that
    ' you really mean that to be "appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range", etc,
    ' (and you probably didn't mean that anyway)
    'Set rngD = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LRow, LCol))
    Set rngD = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1), wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LRow, LCol))

    'To save typing, the previous statements could be written as
    'With wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    '    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    '    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    '    Set rngD = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LRow, LCol))
    'End With

    'This section was probably meant to work on "rngD"
    'For i = 1 To LRow.Rows.Count
    '    If LRow.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
    '        LRow.Cells(i, 11).Value = LRow.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
    '    End If
    'Next
    For i = 1 To rngD.Rows.Count
        If rngD.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
            rngD.Cells(i, 11).Value = rngD.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```